# Interface implementation in Java

Tags: java, interface

I am using the `Dao` pattern in my application, and I tried to use the generic Dao like this:

```
interface IDao<I,T>{
    // CRUD operation
}

abstract class AbstractDaoImpl<I, T> implements IDao<I, T> {
    // reusable method
}

interface UserDao extends IDao<Integer,User>{
    // special method for UserDao
}

class UserDaoImpl  extends AbstractDaoImpl<Integer,User> implements UserDao {
}
```

Notice the `UserDaoImpl` it implements `UserDao`(which extends from `IDao`) itself, while it extends `AbstractDaoImpl` which also implements the `IDao`, which make I though there is duplicate implementation for the interface.

I wonder if this will cause any potential problem? Because I am not sure if this is the acceptable practice in Java.

Comment: It is OK the way you did it.

Answer (score 1):

No, this will not cause problems, because the interface does not contain any implementation (at least until you use Java 8 default methods).

It is not only acceptable, but common practice in Java to factor out general interfaces and only specialize where necessary.

Answer (score -2):

There are 3 ways in Java to implement the interface:

1. Run time polymorphism {function overiding}
2. Using Anonymous class
3. Lambda expression [Applicable only for lambda expression]

**1. Run time polymorphism**
[image]

**2. Using Anonymous class**
[image]

**3. Lambda expression**
[image]

Comment: Please don't put images in your posts: copy/paste the code in the answer.